# Fantasy series about a disabled protagonist

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I've spent years trying to find this book series. I can't remember the name of the book I read, the author, or the characters, but I remember some key parts about the protagonist.

- I think he was an outlaw (or at least wanted), but no one thought it was him since he appeared to be disabled, or that he could barely move properly and needed someone to take care of him (he actually was, but he could make himself "better" per se).
- He was a master swordsman who I think was trained by some special people or society, and he could only act to his full power when he focused on gems.
- Later on in the story or maybe in the next book, he received a special gem thing that I think went on his forehead, which contained several rare gems he could use and meant he didn't need to physically hold the gems.
- Near the end I think it was taken from him in a fight where he nearly dies, but discovers that he can focus without the gems to a certain degree.
- I think there was a character who was part of a church or sanctuary?
- Might have used gems to heal, not knowing how it actually worked, which I think was how the protagonist could move properly, but he did it on himself, but had to be in constant contact with the crystal, which is why the gem thing on his forehead was so important (I think it had an actual name, but no amount of research I've done has found it).

If anyone knows the name of this book, the series it's part of or the author, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [*The Highwayman*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Highwayman_(novel)) by R.A. Salvatore.

From Wikipedia:

> Bransen utilizes both sides of his heritage in the novel to overcome his *crippled state* and become the Highwayman. With help from a *soul stone, the hematite*, combined with his knowledge of The Book of Jhest, *Bransen overcomes his physically weak form by centering his chi, which greatly increases his mobility*. With his newfound ability, he rescues Cadayale from the bullies who wished to rape and beat her for helping him, killing the lead bully, Tarkus Breen. After weeks of robbing from the tax collectors to give back to the poor, becoming a local Robin Hood, Bransen risks everything to rescue Cadayale and Callen from Bernivvigar and Prydae, who sought to rape Cadayale to beget an heir, leading to the deaths of both men.

So it has the main points you mentioned: the main character is an **outlaw**, who avoids suspicion by virtue of his being **crippled**.  He uses a **gem** to focus his energy to make him a superior fighter.  His mother is rescued by Brother Bran Dynard, a follower of   Blessed Abelle, which is probably your **church** reference.